# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'post' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js Ionic 2

Tags: android, angularjs, angular, ionic2

I try to explain in English, but I don't speak it.

I'm working in a Ionic 2. I try to do a http request with post method and I am emulate in SDK Android emulator and  I can see in the logcat:

> Cannot call method 'post' of undefined at
>   file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:2265

But I review and don't see anything, I rewrite my clientId and ClientSecret to can post here. I put a trace console.log(this.http) in the login function and this attribute is undefined, althought is inject in the class' constructor.

My code:

```
import {Page, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
    providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]
})
export class HomePage {

    static get parameters() {
        return [[Platform],[Http]];
    }

    constructor(platform, http) {
        this.platform = platform;
        this.http = http;
        this.clientId = "clientId";
        this.clientSecret = "clientSecret";
    }

    login() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.googleLogin().then((success) => {
                alert(success.access_token);
            }, (error) => {
                alert(error);
            });
        });
    }

    googleLogin() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" + "clientId" + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&scope=email%20profile&approval_prompt=force&response_type=code&access_type=offline", "_blank", "location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes");
            browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
                if ((event.url).indexOf("http://localhost/callback") === 0) {
                    var headers = new Headers();
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    var parameters = "client_id=" + "clientId" + "&client_secret=" + "clientSecret" + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback" + "&grant_type=authorization_code" + "&code=" + requestToken

                    var requestToken = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
                    this.http.post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", parameters, { header:headers })
                    .subscribe( data => { resolve(data); },
                                error => { reject("Problem authenticating with Google"); }
                    );

                    browserRef.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => {});
                    browserRef.close();
                }
            });
            browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function(event) {
                reject("The Google sign in flow was canceled");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The code tries to authenticate with Google OAuth2, althought the error seems to be in the attributes in the constructor(http, clientId, clientSecret) there are not defined when the login function is called. I don't know what's wrong!

Comment: I am not really into javascript, but the error message seems to indicate that a method `post` is called on an undefined object in line 2265.

Comment: `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {` should be `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`. Same with `addEventListener`

Comment: @Henry Yeah, but I am follow several tutorials and I check others codes and i don't saw why did it happening?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am going to change, but the `addEventListener` is working

Comment: That's because you don't use `this.` in the callback passed to `addEventListener()`. You should be consistently using `=>` instead of `function`, only when you explicitely want to execute the passed callback in the scope of the caller, then use `function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't use an arrow function when defining your promise. So the `this` keyword doesn't correspond to the instance of the component itself. With arrow functions, you can use the lexical `this` that will correspond to the component instance.

```
googleLogin() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (...)
  });
}
```

instead of

```
googleLogin() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    (...)
  });
}
```

See this link for more hints about the lexical `this` of arrow functions:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the scoping of 'this', depending on what calls the googleLogin function.
Try using an arrow function:

```
googleLogin = () => {
        ...
}
```